# productos.module.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api

Tengo definido las siguientes importaciones en un proyecto Angular 7, que se venia haciendo en otros componentes en productos.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgSelectModule } from '@ng-select/ng-select';
//*****Implementacion NgX boostrap
import { DatePickerModule } from '../Helpers/DatePicker/DatePicker.module';

import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
//*************************************
//Implementacion Datepicker ng-boostrap
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { NgbdDatepickerPopup } from '../Helpers/DatePicker/DatePickerNgB/DatepickerPopup.component';
```

Como el mensaje de error me sale que no se tiene registrado algo en el tsconfig.json lo expongo ya que no entiendo si el proyecto venia funcionando sin registrar nada en el json

```
{
 "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
 "compilerOptions": {
  "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
  "module": "es2015",
  "types": [ "node" ]
},
"exclude": [
 "src/test.ts",
 "**/*.spec.ts"
]
}
```

Hay algo que omití al crear el modulo?

Soy algo nuevo en angular y creo que me ha faltado algo.
el error especifico cuando hago **ng build** es:

> \src\app\productos\productos.module.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.

**UPDATE**
Se expone el archivo angular.json...

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
   "defaultProject": "co.ProInvestigacion.Web",
   "newProjectRoot": "projects",
   "projects": {
   "co.ProInvestigacion.Web": {
       "root": "",
        "sourceRoot": "src",
       "projectType": "application",
       "prefix": "app",
       "schematics": {},
        "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "progress": true,
        "extractCss": true,
        "outputPath": "dist",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
        "assets": [
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "node_modules/datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.css",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less",
          "src/styles.css",
          "node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.css",
          "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/fontawesome.css",
          "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css",
          "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/brands.css",
          "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/regular.css",
          "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/solid.css",
          "node_modules/@ng-select/ng-select/themes/default.theme.css",
          "node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
          "node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.js",
          "node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/js/dropdown.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/js/modal.js",
          "src/styles.js"
        ]
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true
        }
      }
    },
    "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "co.ProInvestigacion.Web:build"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "co.ProInvestigacion.Web:build:production"
        }
      }
    },
    "extract-i18n": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "co.ProInvestigacion.Web:build"
      }
    },
    "test": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
      "options": {
        "main": "src/test.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
        "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
        "styles": [
          "styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [],
        "assets": [
          "src/assets"
        ]
      }
    },
    "lint": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
      "options": {
        "tsConfig": [
          "src/tsconfig.app.json",
          "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
        ],
        "exclude": [
          "**/node_modules/**"
        ]
      }
    },
    "server": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist-server",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "dev": {
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": true
        },
        "production": {
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
"co.ProInvestigacion.Web-e2e": {
  "root": "e2e/",
  "projectType": "application",
  "architect": {
    "e2e": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
      "options": {
        "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
        "devServerTarget": "co.ProInvestigacion.Web:serve"
      }
    },
    "lint": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
      "options": {
        "exclude": [
          "**/node_modules/**"
        ],
        "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
      }
    }
  }
  }
},
 "version": 1
}
```

la ruta de ese fichero es esta:
**src\app\Productos\productos.module.ts**

Comment: Si es angular quizá deberías exponer el angular.json. ¿Qué path tiene ese fichero? Es `.\src\app\productos\productos.module.ts` correcto?

Comment: @PabloLozano hola, si voy a editar la pregunta y exponer el angular.json

Comment: No sé si estás usando Windows, pero puede ocurrir que el nombre Productos y productos no se vea como el mismo. Prueba a renombrar el directorio

Comment: si era por el caps de productos y Productos YA salen otros warning DatePicker.component.html WARNING in ./src/app/Helpers/DatePicker/DatePickerNgB/DatepickerPopup.component.html
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:

Comment: Es un poco tonto pero... ya paraste completamente `ng serve` y lo iniciaste de nuevo?. Estos dias he encontrado muchos problemas a la hora de cambiar de ramas con git y parece que el compilador no le sientan muy bien estas cosas.

Comment: @Legna ya reinicie hasta el equipo :) :D.... pero gracias por el aporte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución fue eliminar el(los) components productos y volverlo a crear.

al parecer como me indico @PabloLozano si había problema con ".. el nombre Productos y productos no se vea como el mismo. Prueba a renombrar el directorio"

En mi caso lo renombre pero salía nuevamente unos Warning, La Solución fue crear el component nuevamente sin colocar mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Tambien el aporte de @Legna sirvió ya que el versiona miento (TFS de Microsoft) coloca problemas y mantiene elementos en cache.